# Most accurate way to calculate matrix powers and matrix exponential for a positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, approximation, matrix-calculus, numerical-linear-algebra

I do need to numerically calculate the following forms for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, possibly in python:

1. $x^T M^k x$, where $M\in\mathbb{R^n}$ is a PSD matrix, where $k$ can get quite large values $-$possibly up to order of hundreds. I prefer $k$ to be a real number, but it is ok if it can only be an integer, if that makes a considerable accuracy difference.
2. Similarly I am interested in $x^Te^{-tM}x$ where $t$ is a non-positive real value.
   For case 1 I can either:

- Use the [scipy.linalg.fractional_matrix_power](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.fractional_matrix_power.html) to calculate $M^k$ and then derive $x^TM^Kx$, or
- Use [scipy.linalg.svd](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.svd.html) to find SVD of $M$ as $U\Lambda U^T$ and then finally evaluate the desired value using $x^TU\Lambda^k U^Tx$.
- Finally if $k$ is integer, and again based on SVD I can calculate $\|x^TM^{k/2}\|^2$.

For case 2

- Again I can use off the shelf [scipy.linalg.expm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.expm.html) and then exponentiate the singular values of $M$
- I can do SVD for $M$ and then go with $x^TU\exp(\Lambda) U^Tx$.
- Finally since I am only interested in $x^T \exp(M) x$, and not exactly $\exp(M)$ it self, I can consider the Taylor expansion of $x^T{\rm expm}(M)x\approx \sum_{i=0}^{l} \frac{1}{i!}x^TM^ix$ for some $l$ that controls the precision, and $x^TMx$ can be calculated based on case 1.

Can anybody guide me about what is the most precise way to calculate either of these expressions, up to hopefully machine precision? Any of these methods, or they're better solutions out there? I would be happy also with references.

P.S. Not knowing if here or stackoverflow being a good place to share this question at, I will be cross-posting it on their with the same title and content.

Comment: Scicomp stack exchange is a more appropriate place. For what concerns 2, computing the eigendecomposition is a bad idea generally. If the size of the matrix is large, this is going to be even much more problematic. Also, expm computes the full exponential, which is not what you need, because you need the action of such matrix on a vector $x$. So, other techniques should be used (for a survey, take a look at Cleve Moler's famous paper "Nineteen dubious way ..." ).

Comment: There are some robust routines to accomplish this goal now, some of them don't use the positive semidefinitness of the matrix, but they work. There's a method based on rational approximations of $e^{x}$ for $x<=0$ that in the end requires to solve about 10 shifted linear systems. Those techiniques, for sure, are not present in Python

Comment: Also, forget naive Taylor expansions. In the mentioned paper you can see what happens if you try to use them

Comment: Thanks so much @VoB. I have alreday skimmed through "Nineteen...", but didn't notice the special case of $x^T e^{M}x$ but. most likely I missed it. Will take another look now!

Comment: @VoB to add to my previous comment, actually I have read in Moler's work that when $M$ is symmetric, SVD actually can be quite accurate! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Don't to a Taylor expansion! The monomial basis $1,x,x^2, \ldots$ is terribly conditioned. If you want to compute it by a polynomial series, you'd be better of with Chebyshev polynomials. Alternately, you might look into using Lanczos. There is a fair amount of analysis on computing the matrix exponential via Lanczos. It should be reasonably straightforward and inexpensive to compute to machine precision this way.

Comment: There are even some python packages to compute $\exp(M)x$: https://weinbe58.github.io/QuSpin/generated/quspin.tools.lanczos.expm_lanczos.html. You can take that output and then take the inner product with $x$ to get the quadratic form you want.

Comment: Thanks so much @tch!! I was just checking that. The only tricky thing is that apparnetly Lanczos is for action of $\exp(M)$ on $x$ where I am interested still on a simpler thing which is $x^T\exp(M)x$. I can obviously go with $\|\exp(M/2)x\|^2$ but I am not sure if that's the best idea.

Comment: Once you have $v = \exp(M)x$, you can compute $x^T\exp(M)x$ as $x^Tv$. Actually, there are computational advantages to computing the quadratic form via Lanczos (You dont need to save the krylov subspace), so if your matrix is very big, you may look for a package which implements this, or write it yourself.

Comment: @tch I guess there is a misunderstanding. $x^Texp(M)x$ is a number

Comment: @VoB, do you mind giving me a reference for those accurate methods not implemented in python?

Comment: @Cupitor The keyword is "Chebychev rational approximation of $e^{x}$". There's a famous paper by Gallopoulos and Saad which gives a practical way (see the middle of page. 9 https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/PDF/CSRD_90_969.pdf ) and also a correction on the coefficients of the linear combination which has been provided more recently (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.2880.pdf). In the end you're required to solve linear systems. This methods works for $A$ negative semidefinite, if you apply it to arbitrary matrices, it's not gonna work

Comment: Thanks so much @VoB. That definitely helps! And also thanks for the final headsup

Answer (score 2):

One standard approach to computing matrix functions times a vector $f(M)x$ or quadratic forms $x^Tf(M)x$ when $M$ is symmetric is via the [Lanczos algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm). Lanczos computes an orthonormal basis $Q_k = [q_1, \ldots, q_k]$ for Krylov subspace $\operatorname{span}(x,Ax,\ldots, A^{k-1}x)$ by a Gram-Schmidt like procedure. This results in a factorization $AQ_k =Q_kT_k + \beta_k q_{k+1}e_k^T$, where $e_k$ is the $k$-th canonical basis vector and $T_k$ is a $k\times k$ symmetric tridiagonal matrix.

The "Lanczos approximation" $f(M)x$ is defined as $Q_k f(T_k) Q_k^T x$, and the approximation to $x^Tf(M)x$ is defined as $x^TQ_k f(T_k) Q_k^T x$. There are [software packages](http://weinbe58.github.io/QuSpin/generated/quspin.tools.lanczos.expm_lanczos.html) to compute $Q_k f(T_k) Q_k^T x$. This can easily be turned into the Lanczos approximation to $x^Tf(M)x$ by taking the inner product with $x$. The Lanczos approximation to the quadratic form can be viewed as a certain Gaussian quadrature approximation to $x^T f(M) x$ and converges extremely quickly in $k$ if $f$ is analytic (see Golub Meurant "Matrices Moments and Quadrature").

This approach has runtime $O(T_{mv}k + nk)$ (or $O(T_{mv}k + nk^2)$ with full reorthogonalization), where $T_{mv}$ is the cost of evaluating $v\mapsto Mv$. This will almost certainly be cheaper than an SVD or any $n^3$ algorithm since $k$ can typically be taken to be fairly small even for a machine precision accurate output.

Note that if $x$ is unit length $Q_k^Tx = e_1$. This means the Lanczos approximation to $x^Tf(M)x$ is given by $e_1^T f(T_k) e_1$ and that $Q_k$ doesn't need to be stored. There are also some subtleties about whether full reorthogonalization should be used or not. Whether or not it is used, the output will still be [accurate](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S1064827596303661?journalCode=sjoce3), but without reorthogonalization $k$ may need to be larger. However, reorthogonalizaton is more computationally expensive, so there is some tradeoff.

Comment: thanks so much! The question is also posted in scicomp and you might want to add your answer there too: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36922. I think your answer covers the $e^M$ case. Do you have any idea of how to handle $M^k$? I assume by taking $f$ to be quadratic? Also the wiki link does not clarify how to replace $M$ with $f(M)$ could you link to something for that.

Comment: btw, the Golub Meurant et. al. reference is so useful for theoretical understanding. I wish I could have double-upvoted the post. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can do it the same way with $f(x) = x^i$. If $i<k$, then Lanczos will be exact. However, again computing $A^i$ is not a good idea numerically.

Comment: again I don't get how I can aply $f$? I don't see it in the wiki article either. How does one apply the $f$, considering that $T_k$ is a tridiagonal matrix?

Comment: It is using the standard definition of a matrix function. So you compute the eigendecompsoition of $T_k$. But since it is tridiagonal and symmetric, this can be done very quickly.

Comment: so does that mean I need to write $T_k$'s expansion as $U\Lambda_k U^T$ and then apply $f$ to the singular values of it?

Comment: Yeah, but this can be done in $O(k^2)$ becaues $T_k$ is tridiagonal. Most numerical libraries have a function for the eigendecomposition of a tridiagonal matrix.

Comment: Yeah yeah, I am just trying to make sure I understand. Thank you ver much!